# How to add css depending on a field value?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a field attached to a node which contains an image or not.

If there is an image I should load a specific css(sass).

How can I do this?

Comment: Try [hook_css_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you need to [drupal_add_css](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_css/7.x) in your [template_preprocess_node](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7.x) in your `template.php` after checking the condition that image exists in a manner similar to

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
if ($field) {
   //Do something with the field
}
else{
   //There are no results
}
```